# Context Switching to Specific Process after Specific ISR

Tags: c, linux, interrupt, isr, context-switching

Is there any (dirty)method to provoke context switching to specific process after specific ISR?

In normal situation, after an ISR, the process which was interrupted will keep running, and I have to wait the scheduler to pick that specific process. I want to switch to the specific process right away after the ISR.

Any advice will be great. Thanks!

Comment: 'In normal situation, after an ISR, the process which was interrupted will keep running' - no, not always, and making a thread/process ready upon a hardware interrupt does not need any (dirty)method, it's normal behaviour for drivers when an I/O operation is completed, usually using semaphore or event signaling and requesting a scheduler run upon return from interrupt state.

Comment: If there is a core free, or if your waiting thread is of high enough priority to preempt whatever was running on the cores before the interrupt, your thread/process will be made running, rather than just ready.

Answer (score 2):

Construct your driver so that the process has a thread blocking on suitable syscall (`read()`, `ioctl()`) with the ISR waking up that thread (because at least one byte became available for `read()`).

Then, make sure that thread has the highest priority possible, and preferably uses a realtime scheduler (`SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`). In practice, if your process does not run with root privileges, you'll need to start the service with root privileges, setup the thread, then drop privileges; or give the binary executable `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability via e.g. [`setcap pe=CAP_SYS_NICE binary`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html).

It is technically possible for the driver to also mess with the scheduling, but I would not do that.  Anything that is so time-critical, should be done in the kernel ISR instead.

If you want to do it in userspace, because you don't want your code to be a derivative of the kernel and therefore GPL-licensed, you're on your own.